# How to get the nested childrens of my Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested, parent-child

I need to get the children of the children of my database from this key,

I attach a photo to make it better understood

[image: photo]

my ref

```
  public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_LIKED_KEY);
}
public static DatabaseReference getPostLikedRef(String postId) {
    return getPostLikedRef().child(getCurrentUser().getEmail()
            .replace(".", ","))
            .child(postId);
}


// post ref


 public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constants.POSTS_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Why are there commas in the emails?

Comment: @cricket_007 for preference

Comment: @cricket_007 Firebase Database keys cannot contain periods. Using a comma as a replacement is idiomatic, since commas are not valid in email addresses anyway.

Comment: @Frank Haven't come across that yet. I'm guessing dot notation would be interpreted as nested keys? Or Mongo doesn't support dots in keys

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 
Thanks for the answer, it is correct and you clarified doubts and  Sorry for not being able to give a concrete answer I'm still new to this

Comment: @TheQuestionerXxx I didn't ask anything, but instead answered cricket's question. As for you own post, I'm not quite sure I understand what you're problem is. Can't you read the data with a value event? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem is that I want to have as a counter "likes" to receive the "likes" of all users and well I know how to do it

Comment: Did you try reading the data yet? The code you shared does nothing more than define references to some locations in the database. The documentation I linked has examples on how to then read data from those locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts_liked").child(userEmail);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot != null) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if (map != null) {
            //Do everything you want
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The data you need is inside that `map`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!